# Windows 8.1: Aero Snap Artifact Left on Screen

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, aero

I am using Windows 8.1, with [this program (Re-Adds Aero Glass](http://glass8.eu).

Obviously the Aero Snap and similar features are still included in Win8.1, even if the Glass effects aren't, which I'm using the program above (Glass8) to replicate

However, occasionally when I snap windows, they leave an box Artifact on screen that won't go away unless I restart. See below: *(Left Hand Edge of My Screen)*

[image: Left Hand Edge of My Screen]

I have tried restarting explorer.exe, and dwm won't let me kill it it seems.

Any help for this large annoyance would be very appreciated!

Comment: ask this in the official support forum at msfn and share the **debug.log**: http://www.msfn.org/board/forum/180-aero-glass-for-windows-8/

Comment: @magicandre1981 OK, sounds like a good idea.